# How to get a Product's Category?

Tags: php, magento

New to PHP so I apologise for the apparent simplicity of this problem.

I understand that you can get a product's categories by doing this:

```
//load the product
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

//load the categories of this product 
$categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
```

But how to do I get just the first product of the category?

Comment: $categoryCollection[0]?

Answer (score 0):

The getCategoryCollectionn function returns a Magento collection containing all of the product's categories.  The items in the category collection are Magento category objects, and a category has a method (`getProductsCollection`) that returns a collection containing all of the products in the category.  Magento collections have a fairly rich API that can be used to fetch specific items from the collection, in  this case we want `getFirstItem()`.   To put that all together:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
    $products = $category->getProductsCollection();

    // Here we have the first product
    $firstProduct = $products->getFirstItem();
}
```

If all you want is the first product in the first category for you current product, you could avoid the loop and do this instead:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$categoryCollection = $product->getCategoryCollection();
$category = $categoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
$products = $category->getProductsCollection();

// Here we have the first product
$firstProduct = $products->getFirstItem();
```

Note: Neigher of these code samples are particularly efficient, but without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I can't propose a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}
```